# document.mutate.save is undefined

Tags: php, javascript, modx, modx-evolution

I'm using the ModX CMS.

And this error, `document.mutate.save is undefined` keeps coming up if I were to save a chunk.

Assuming it was a faulty install, I deleted the application, and reinstalled it four times. Those included:

1. Twice from the original working application on my testing remote server.
2. From the latest version of Evolution on ModX's website
3. From another working site I maintain that was also created in ModX.

Assuming it was a javascript conflict, I went into my QM, and removed jQuery from the backend, and then eventually removed jQuery all together unsure if it was still being placed in there. I can not view the source of the backend because it is entirely composed out of iFrames.

The document.mutate.save files come from a folder located in: `/manager/actions`/

This folder is set to `777` as well as all the surrounding golders and the parent `manager` folder as well.

Anyone have any idea as to why this error is being called, and how to fix it?

I'm a rails guy, but this seems like a simple method not being defined in the controller problem. Unfortunately, I'm not too conscious of PHP's MVC architecture otherwise, I would fix this manually.

Thanks!

Comment: I have this problem with about 20+ modx sites, have yet to find a solution. It isn't to do with the install. There are a lot of javascript bugs in modx, this one is pervasive.

Comment: @thelastshadow I moved on to Wordpress. Couldn't be more happier.

Comment: really? I don't like CMSes in general but WordPress is the one that annoys me the most.

Comment: Hmm. interesting. it's got what i need with relative ease, and a huge community to boot. it seems to have the most progressive bells and whistles compared to all the others. but I agree..who needs a CMS when you can code things from scratch. in my case, i make a lot of small sites for a lot of people, and this gets the basics out of the way with a good sense of professionalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old thread, I know... but I have a possible solution which worked for me.
After a lot of fiddling around, I finally found that I had activated the editor in the configurations, but had uninstalled the TinyMCE Plugin. After deactivating the editor, the error disappeared.